# Default RSA padding in SUN JCE/Oracle JCE

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

Could you help me to point out what is the default RSA padding.

Precisely, if I create cipher instance as below, sure java is using some sort of padding as encrypted text bytes length always shows 256 bytes for 2048 RSA key irrespective of plain text is one characters or 10 characters.

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
```

I wanted to know what is default padding java use internally if no padding is specified in Cipher.getInstance("RSA"). is that PKCS#1 v 1.5?

Thanks, 
Sam

Answer (score 19):

It's identical to `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` where ECB is a bit of a misnomer, as it does not implement a block cipher mode of operation (it doesn't handle plaintext larger than the "block size"). `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"` would have been a better name or `"RSA/None/RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5"` as your guess about the padding mechanism is correct.

This means that it uses a older mode of encryption; OAEP is more resistant against attacks and contains a security proof. Unfortunately OAEP can of course not be made the new default because all existing ciphertext would not decrypt anymore. This is one of the reasons why using defaults is stupid in the first place.

PKCS#1 v1.5 padding also means that the input is restricted to a maximum of the key size minus 11 bytes. Note that the size of the resulting ciphertext is always identical to the key size in PKCS#1; even if the resulting integer is smaller it will be left padded with zero bytes. I'm assuming here that the key size is a multiple of 8.

You should not rely on defaults for the algorithm specification. It makes the code harder to understand and defaults may indeed differ per provider (although most will try to follow Oracle's lead, to avoid incompatibilities). So use this only to understand which algorithm is configured in existing code. The only place where a platform default makes sense is `SecureRandom` in my opinion.